# Control doesn't sift through photos in company page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

While browsing a company page, e.g. of [CheckedUp](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/checkedup), I see photos but the controls that move you back and forth don't work: (clicking either of them has no effect)

[image]

Tested in latest version of Chrome and Firefox. As you can see there are two pictures, and clicking them directly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [our company page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) and you'll see what these buttons do! :-)

Comment: That makes sense, so don't you think those arrows should be hidden then if they serve no purpose?  PS: Joel needs to spend more money on bananas those bananas are about as ripe as you can get!

Comment: @JonH he better spend the money on more bacon for Jin, we don't want the design to get wonky!!

Comment: Poor Jin, every comment I see about design has his name on it...maybe its time to hire more designers?  Or is everyone else whose a designer there just not getting enough credit :).

Comment: @JonH lol, actually there are at least two more designers, he's just the most veteran and well known. :)

Comment: Max, so [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: yes, status-bydesign.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. Those arrows are meant to sift through **pages** of pictures, not single pictures.

So as long as there are less than 8 pictures, those buttons don't really have any use.

For example [Stack Exchange company page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange) contains 20 pictures which means 3 pages, so the buttons are active in there:

[image]

Comment: Well that isn't nice - its confusing :).

Comment: @JonH yes, a little. :)